# Laravel select where/count query

Tags: mysql, laravel, select, count

There are two Mysql tables:

---

1.reservations(id,screening_id,reserved). the reserved is a boolean its value "1".

---

2. table seat_reserveds(id,screening_id,reservation_id,seat_id).

---

I want the following:
1.get the reservation id
 select id from reservation where screening_id = id and reserved = 1
In laravel looks like:

```
          $reservation_id = DB::table('reservations')->select('id')- 
          >where('screening_id',$id)->where('reserved','1')->get();
```

Then I want to count how many seats are reserved

---

Select count(id) from seat_resrveds where where screening_id = id and reservtain_id = id.
In laravel looks like:

```
        $reservedtickets = DB::table('seat_reseverds')- 
       >where('screening_id',$id)->where('reservation_id',$reservation_id)->count('id');
```

I think the problam is that I get  "id":number from $reservation_id so cant use it at the $reservedtitckets query because I only need a number.
How can I write these querys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `->value('id')` to get a single value from a query:

```
$reservation_id = DB::table('reservations')
    ->where('screening_id',$id)
    ->where('reserved','1')
    ->value('id');
```

Comment: @Blasanka - It's not even "eloquent" - It's just the query builder.

Answer (score 0):

Update the query to the following.

```
    $reservation = DB::table('reservations')
      ->where('screening_id',$id)
      ->where('reserved', 1)
      ->first();
```

Then the `$reservation_id` should be as below.

```
$reservation_id = $reservation->id;
```

You can pass this parameter to your next query for `$reservedtickets`.